# php script for Collaborative translation?

Tags: php

I'm looking for a PHP script to build Collaborative translation site where multiple users, can translate words/sentences and view/edit or add their comments on translations (like Launchpad translation system)..

is there anything like this ?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's not tailored to your specific need, an approach that would work is to set up a wiki site. You can get wikipedia's php code [here](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki) or a google search will show dozens of other options.

Answer (score 0):

http://blog.launchpad.net/general/launchpad-is-now-open-source

Launchpad itself is open source.